# MS Git Provider and Git line ending handling in-consistency

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

I've come onto a team that has been using the Git virtually exclusively through the MS Git provider in VS2015. If I do source control operations exclusively through the MS Git provider everything works as expected. However, I like to use more of Git than is available via the MS Git Provider. As soon as I do a Git Status at the command prompt or open the repository with Git Extensions it identifies files as having changes even through they have not changed. It's a line-ending issue verified by doing `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol`.

Inside VS I have the `core-autocrlf=false` and in the .gitconfig file I have it set the same.

.gitAttributes with nothing, MS Git provider works great, but Git and Git extensions report many files as being different.  If I set an entry in .gitAttributes `text=auto` it immediate sets GIT and Git extensions correctly, but then MS Git provider reports many files as different.

It appears I have an either use MS Git provider exclusively or use Git\Git Extensions. I can't find a combination that works for both.

Answer (score 1):

I finally settled on the an entry in .gitAttributes `text=auto` file. There were a number of files that had to be check-in (with no real fixes) in order to resolve. Once past that phase, using the .gitattributes file worked great.